# MVC3 Razor Syntax troubles

Tags: syntax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to make a very simple view using Razor syntax in MVC3, but it seems I can't get the syntax right.

I have a simple table like this

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    @{
                        var counter = 0;
                    }

                    @foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="@("category" + category.Code)" />
                            @category.Description
                        </td>

                        if (counter % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            </table>
```

When I insert the  and  inside the if-statement, I receive this error

> The using block is missing a closing "}" character.

If I try to wrap those two tags inside  and , I get this error instead:

> The "tr" element was not closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `</tr><tr>` messes up the "flow" of the html/code mix.

You are closing the tr-tag on a different level, not a different level in the html, but inside the code. You should trick razor into outputting html, that it does not parse itself.

You could include them like this:

```
@:</tr><tr>
```

or

```
@Html.Raw("</tr><tr>")
```

The result:

```
                        if (counter % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            @:</tr><tr>
                        }
```

Click for Haack's [quick reference of Razor syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: +1 Aside from Phils quick reference I would love to have a complete reference out there.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah me too. Although the syntax is real easy and nice to use.

Comment: I'm wondering if that would be something for a community wiki? I could really use it. Even if the razor syntax is very clean, sometimes it messes with my brain ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would say you're missing the @ in front of the if statement. Try `@if(counter % 2 == 0)`.

Hope that helps.

**Update**

I checked it out and the answer from [GvS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827354/mvc3-razor-syntax-troubles/4827491#4827491) seems to work just fine. The @ is not necessary for the if statement.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (i == 3)
    {
        @:</tr><tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? He is directly inside a Razor code block, not surrounded by tags. The `if` should work without @

Comment: Because the contents are mixed.

Comment: @GvS: I checked it and you are right. `@:</tr><tr>` works fine.

Comment: jfauffin: But he is already outside the `<td>` tag. So he is back at code-level. Razor understands the if without @. (At least on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing HTML and code in the foreach. That's why you get problems.

Either use `<text></text>` block around the HTML, or do the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @{
            var counter = 0;
        }

        @foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
        {
            @{ 
                counter++; 
            }

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="@("category" + category.Code)" />
                @category.Description
            </td>

            @if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                </tr>
                <tr>
            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```