# Using divs in a looping list

Tags: css, loops, html, modal-window

So i'm currently working on this project where I display an list in MVC 4 ListView. One of my fields has a large amount of data so instead of displaying this info in table, I made a CSS modal window to display. Here's a snippet of my HTML with the ListView and clickable modal view:

```html
                <table class="srrTable">
                    <tr>

                        <th>
                             Dwelling Id
                        </th>
                        <th>
                             Postal Address Id
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Insuance Policy Id
                        <th>
                            XML Text
                       </th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DwellingIdentifier)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostalAddressIdentifier)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsurancePolicyIdentifier)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="xmllabel" href="#xmlmodal">View</a>
                                <div id="xmlmodal">
                                    <div class="xmlmodal">
                                        <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
                                        <h2>XMLText</h2>
                                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.XMLText)</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
```

I used [this take](http://jsfiddle.net/WctVs/3/) on [this tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-an-adaptive-css-modal-window/) to make the modal window.

However when I click on my link to display the XMLText, it shows the first XMLText for all of the row when they should be different. If I was displaying this normally without the div all the XMLTexts are the correct element for the column. I guess I don't understand why this doesn't work (Because it's a hidden div? because of the link?) and was just looking for an explanation and maybe some guidance on how to get my XMLText to display properly.

As for the CSS, I followed the tutorial exactly so please refer to my links. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

---

### RE-UPDATE:

After implementing the suggestions below the field in my table looks like this:

```html
.
.
.
                            <div class="Hidden">@(counter++)</div>
                            <td>
                            <a class="xmllabel" href="#xmlmodal@(counter)">View</a>
                            <div id="xmlmodal@(counter)" class="showhidexmlmodal">
                                <div class="showhidexmlmodal@(counter)">
                                    <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
                                    <h2>XMLText</h2>
                                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.XMLText)</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
.
.
.
```

I added the `.showhidexmlmodal` as suggested and updated my CSS:

```css
a.xmllabel {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #232323;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/50px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.xmllabel:hover {
  background: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input#xmltoggle {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}

#xmlmodal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.showhidexmlmodal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7 );

  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);

  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease, z-index 1s ease;
}

.showhidexmlmodal a.close {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    background: #232323;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font: 14px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.showhidexmlmodal h2 {
  color: #232323;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 35px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.showhidexmlmodal p {
  color: #444;
  text-align: left;
  font: 13px/1.8 Georgia, Times, sans-serif;
}

.showhidexmlmodal:target, .showhidexmlmodal:target > .xmlmodal {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .xmlmodal {
        width: 300px;
        height: 250px;
    }

        .xmlmodal h2 {
            font: 30px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

    .xmlmodal p {
        font: 12px/1.8 Georgia, Times, sans-serif;
    }
}
```

This code is showing the correct XML text now, but my black cover #xmlmodal isn't showing. Any suggestions?

Its ignoring the css that goes with the xmlmodal id.

(Disclamer to new viewers: I'm extremely new to web programming and concept of `div`s)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what is supposed to happen and what actually happens? Also, could you make a fiddle of your own?

Comment: @MrLister It's complicated to make a fiddle because what my project is doing is retrieving a table of policy rating responses from a database and storing them in a list which is displayed with a MVC ListView. The last column holds an XMLText file which has all the important rating information. The xml string is very long so I decided I would use the modal-window style to show the information. So like the fiddle I referred to, I have one of the toggle buttons in each field of the XMLText column, but they all display the first xml text in the list.

Comment: Do the divs in all the table rows really all have the same id? In that case, the links will get confused and won't know which div to make visible. Make sure the ids are unique.

Comment: @MrLister Yes they all show the data first div should be displaying. So it is because they have the same id and i'm looping through my list to display? I'm new to web programming so sorry if this seems obvious. I thought it would still show the right data because if I display the xml text in the actual call like the others it works out fine.

Comment: Sorry, my comment took a few edits before it came out right. Yes, if you have two (or more) divs with `id="xmlmodal"` and you do something with `#xmlmodal` in CSS, the div that is affected may not be the div you expect.

Comment: Mr Lister is correct. The normal solution is to change from an ID to a class, because multiple elements can have the same class. However, you need IDs in this case, because only IDs can be anchor points you can link to. So I think you need to generate unique IDs like `xmlmodal1`, `xmlmodal2`, etc. in the loop.

Comment: @MrLister okay which I do because i'm looping through... Thank you this is helpful. Do you if there's any way around this or maybe a better solution to what i'm trying to accomplish (basically a nice way to display the large amount of data) or a different way to make a modal window work?

Comment: @RoryO'Kane do you have a reference article or example you could send me to help me generate unique CSS ids? Like I said to Mr Lister, i'm very new to all these concepts. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827354/mvc3-razor-syntax-troubles

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I've progressed farther the with project, just stuck on one more piece. I re-edited the Update post to show the newer code. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to make the ids for the divs unique.

I don't have my Visual Studio handy, but I think it goes something like this:

```
@{var counter = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
  .
  .
  .
    @{counter++;}
    <a class="xmllabel" href="#xmlmodal@(counter)">View</a>
    <div id="xmlmodal@(counter)" class="showhidexmlmodal">
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: As per the comments below, I added a class to the `div` with the `id`, so you can pinpoint those with the CSS. Simple replace all `#xmlmodal` with `.showhidexmlmodal`. (You can use any class name you want of course, as log as it isn't an existing class in the CSS.)
Note: only in the CSS file, not in the `href`s in the example above!

Comment: So now in my CSS file will I need to have xmlmodal1, xmlmodel2, and so on defined? If so, this will not work because it's a dynamic list. I tested it out with my code and it broke the modal-window view completely. Thank you for your help though

Comment: You mean you have something like `div#xmlmodal1:target` in your CSS? I'm not sure you need to address the id in the CSS at all. `div:target` may be enough. But I can't test here now, sorry.

Comment: I have this #xmlmodal:target, #xmlmodal:target > .xmlmodal {...} should this take care of the numbers? The numbers on the end are displaying in the cell and the html broke.

Comment: @juleekwin That CSS would not take care of the numbers. To fix this, change the CSS selectors to match the *classes* of the `<div>`s (but keep the `<a>` links linking to the IDs). Give each `<div>` a class by adding `class="xmlmodal"` to the `<div>` in the loop. The class will be the same for each `<div>`, so the selector `.xmlmodal` will match all of the `<div>`s.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane There are already divs with class=xmlmodal in the source. Not sure how the construct works exactly, but I think it's better to make a new class for the ones that now have the id. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MrLister Hey guys, I tried to implement what you said but I still don't have it working. I will put an edit at the bottom of my post to show what my html and css look like now. When I select a view I get a 404 error.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane please look at comment above if you think you could possibly help!